# WPF app closes itself after a while sometimes

Tags: wpf, multithreading

The app is using my library which works using threads to do some operation; also it uses SIP VOIP library (obviously it is using threads). GUI is bound to interfaces of both libraries.
I noticed a weird behavior of my app. Usually it works just fine but sometimes after some time (3-5 minutes) it suddenly closes.
It is too irregular to debug it or diagnose.

Anyone had that kind of problem? Any idea what could be the reason for that?

Comment: This is very vague. It could be one of the libraries failing. You probably have to diagnose this issue although it's rare.

Comment: We can't answer this.If you can't replicate the behavior it become nearly impossible for us to help. Is it possible to add any tracing to the application? Are there any logs (event log?)?

Comment: I know it is a hard one. Logger is not implemented yet, it's going to be, but after some crucial elements. Well, I guess voip lib is good, because it is popular and pretty expensive ;) My lib is using threads, but I can see in VS output that they are ended properly. Well I guess I'll try to get some more info from app when it'll be possible. Thanks

Comment: It's just guessing, even voip lib could be wrong. Logging should be in your application from day one. It is a crucial element. Just imagine what would happen if you continue to add functionality while the current bug remains... you might be forced to throw it all out. Fix bugs first, add stuff later.

Comment: Do you have a handler for unhandled exceptions? If not, implement one.

Comment: I totally agree with PVitt, you should add a handler at least on AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, and log the Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you add an application level error handler so that you can log any errors that are occuring that you might be missing. It is as simple as

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += HandleApplicationException;
```

Here is an MSDN article that describes it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx

Comment: I did it after PVitt and Vivien Ruiz comments, these are handled now, but unfortunately my app don't want to close itself! I need to wait for the bug to occur. Thanks anyway Matt

Comment: I added callbacks: <pre><code>Application_DispatcherUnhandledException</code></pre> and
<pre><code>AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException</code></pre> like You said. Unfortunately it didn't give me to the source of the problem. My app closed and non of these callbacks were called. I am working on some logger according to what Erno wrote.